# Regex doesn't match. Online generator does

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement

I've want to check with a regex this kind of string:

2020_2021_01_01

I've putted it in a variable, say $session

so i do:

```
if  [[  "$session" =~ \d{4}[_]\d{4}[_]\d{2}[_]\d{2} ]]; then
    stuff
fi
```

you see...it doesn't work... but I don't know why....

any help?
THANKS!

Comment: When you say 'online generator does', does that mean you've tried it on a web application for regexp? could you provide a link? Also, what is the output? How does it differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_005b_005b) rather tersely explains that when the `=~` operator "is used, the string to the right of the operator is considered an extended regular expression and matched accordingly (as in regex(3))".

Here, `regex(3)` is a reference to `man 3 regex`, which might explain what an "extended regular expression" is. A longer description would be "Posix standard extended regular expressions", and you can find the documentation for those in the [Posix document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html). If you're using an online regular expression tester, make sure you select "Posix regular expressions".

In short, they don't include Perlisms like `\d`. You can write `[[:digit:]]` or (if you are using the C locale) `[0-9]`.

So your regex could have been written:

```
([[:digit:]]{4}_){2}[[:digit:]]{2}_[[:digit:]]{2}
```

(there is no need to quote <kbd>_</kbd>). However, be aware that the `=~` operator looks for a substring which matches the pattern, rather than testing whether the left-hand operator precisely matches the pattern. So you quite possibly actually wanted an anchored match:

```
^([[:digit:]]{4}_){2}[[:digit:]]{2}_[[:digit:]]{2}$
```

Answer (score 0):

The backslash character is an escape character in bash shell. In your example, I think that's making the the regular expression read like this:

```
d{4}[_]d{4}[_]d{2}[_]d{2}
```

You could confirm this by testing, setting $session to `dddd_dddd_dd_dd`

To workaround this, to preserve the backslash character in the regular expression, you'll need to "escape" it. In your case, preceding each backslash with an "extra" backslash may do the trick. The shell will see the two backslashes, and leave the second one, as part of the string.

```
if  [[  "$session" =~ \\d{4}[_]\\d{4}[_]\\d{2}[_]\\d{2} ]]; then
```

I'm not sure if there are other characters that are going to need to be escaped. This calls for a real short script, one that you can change and run, to figure out what's working and whats not. Can you match the start of the string, a single digit character, etc.

(The whole escaping thing gets funkier... inside double quotes, inside single quotes, ...)

There was a website I used to use, put in the string I wanted, and it would give me back what it needed to look like in the shell script, I don't have a link to that anymore. There's probably a regular expression tester that let's you test "bash" regular expressions.

Comment: Actually, \d doesn't work in posix regexen. But you're right that if it did work, it would need to be written with an extra escape, because bash doesn't let you quote regex operators (quoted characters are self-matching, regardless of what they are).